# Comment flags & upvote arrows - another change?

Tags: discussion, bug

This is another of my "Am I going mad or did this behaviour change recently?" questions.

I'm sure the grey upvote & flag icons didn't used to appear unless you hovered over them. Now they seem to be visible all the time.

Image from a long thread of comments - the only ones without a visible icon pair are my own comments.
I upvoted one so you can see the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was part of a recent UI change to make flagging more obvious.

> As mentioned by Monica, this is an intentional change to make flagging more discoverable. We can all agree it definitely does that.
>
> This is a work in progress and we are working on some additional changes to improve the layout of comments. These changes will build on the changes we made to make comments responsive and will use our Stacks design library. As you can imagine and as this post proves, changes to comments layout can be controversial, so I'll post more as we rollout additional changes.

[Why are the comment upvote and flag options always appearing now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312794/222623)

Some CSS can reverse this change:

```
.comments-list > .comment:not(:hover) > .comment-actions > :not(.comment-score) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yet another 'improvement'... & I've not a clue what to do with CSS.

Comment: @Tetsujin Agreed, should be rep dependent if anything. I’m away from my computer to add screenshots/instructions but you should be able to add it to a CSS file that you choose in Safari Preferences > Advanced > Style Sheet